# Want to Receive Data over USB OTG HS via DMA

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, usb-otg

I am trying to receive data over USB OTG HS via DMA on an STM32F4 Discovery board. I have enabled the internal IP DMA, but I am not sure how to receive data with it. I have attempted to modify the code inside `usbd_conf.h`, but so far it has proven unsuccessful. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```c
/**
  * @brief  Data In stage callback.
  * @param  hpcd: PCD handle
  * @param  epnum: Endpoint number
  * @retval None
  */
#if (USE_HAL_PCD_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1U)
static void PCD_DataInStageCallback(PCD_HandleTypeDef *hpcd, uint8_t epnum)
#else
void HAL_PCD_DataInStageCallback(PCD_HandleTypeDef *hpcd, uint8_t epnum)
#endif /* USE_HAL_PCD_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
{
   if (hpcd->Instance == USB_OTG_HS && epnum == 0)
   {
       /* Process received data here */
       uint32_t received_length = sizeof(rx_buffer) - HAL_PCD_EP_GetRxCount(hpcd, 0);
       if (received_length > 0) {
           // Toggle the LED
           HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);

           // Copy received data to the buffer for debugging
           memcpy(&received_data_buffer[received_data_length], rx_buffer, received_length);
           received_data_length += received_length;

           // Restart the reception
           HAL_PCD_EP_Receive(hpcd, 0, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));
       }
   }
   USBD_LL_DataInStage((USBD_HandleTypeDef*)hpcd->pData, epnum, hpcd->IN_ep[epnum].xfer_buff);
}

/*******************************************************************************
                       LL Driver Interface (USB Device Library --> PCD)
*******************************************************************************/

/**
  * @brief  Initializes the low level portion of the device driver.
  * @param  pdev: Device handle
  * @retval USBD status
  */
USBD_StatusTypeDef USBD_LL_Init(USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev)
{
   /* Init USB Ip. */
   if (pdev->id == DEVICE_HS) {
      /* Link the driver to the stack. */
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.pData = pdev;
      pdev->pData = &hpcd_USB_OTG_HS;

      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Instance = USB_OTG_HS;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.dev_endpoints = 6;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.speed = PCD_SPEED_HIGH;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.dma_enable = ENABLE;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.phy_itface = USB_OTG_ULPI_PHY;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.Sof_enable = DISABLE;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.low_power_enable = DISABLE;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.lpm_enable = DISABLE;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.vbus_sensing_enable = DISABLE;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.use_dedicated_ep1 = DISABLE;
      hpcd_USB_OTG_HS.Init.use_external_vbus = DISABLE;
      if (HAL_PCD_Init(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS) != HAL_OK) {
         Error_Handler( );
      }

      #if (USE_HAL_PCD_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1U)
      /* Register USB PCD CallBacks */
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_SOF_CB_ID, PCD_SOFCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_SETUPSTAGE_CB_ID, PCD_SetupStageCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_RESET_CB_ID, PCD_ResetCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_SUSPEND_CB_ID, PCD_SuspendCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_RESUME_CB_ID, PCD_ResumeCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_CONNECT_CB_ID, PCD_ConnectCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, HAL_PCD_DISCONNECT_CB_ID, PCD_DisconnectCallback);

      HAL_PCD_RegisterDataOutStageCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, PCD_DataOutStageCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterDataInStageCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, PCD_DataInStageCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterIsoOutIncpltCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, PCD_ISOOUTIncompleteCallback);
      HAL_PCD_RegisterIsoInIncpltCallback(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, PCD_ISOINIncompleteCallback);
      #endif /* USE_HAL_PCD_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      HAL_PCDEx_SetRxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, 0x200);
      HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, 0, 0x80);
      HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, 1, 0x174);
   }
   return USBD_OK;
}
```